# Crashlytics Fabric badly handles throw std::exception invoked from swift ios on 32 bit platforms

Tags: c++, ios, swift, crashlytics

We have a bit of a problem with Fabric framework for iOS ver. 3.0.10.

When we invoke this on 32 bit iOS simulators (we haven't tested it on any 32 bit devices yet but we know it works on 64 bit devices):

```
try {
   throw std::exception();
} catch ( ... ) {
   // do smth with it ...
}
```

we get a SIGABRT signal on the line with "throw". On 64 bit platforms it is all fine however.

The code is invoked from swift and we use latest Xcode version : 6.3.2 (6D2105).

Is there a way to make this work on ver. 3.0.10 of Fabric ?

Also its worth mentioning that it works perfectly fine on Fabric ver. 3.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

There was a linker bug in Xcode 6.1 - 6.3 that was confirmed by Apple engineers at WWDC, and has a confirmed fix in Xcode 7, with a potential, but unconfirmed fix in Xcode 6.4.

You can tell that you're affected if you see a warning mentioning "Personality Functions" when linking your application. As of 3.0.10, Crashlytics.framework is no longer built with an affected version of Xcode. To make sure you're not hit by this bug, any other static library as well as your main app **must not be built** with an affected version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks Mike ! We will check it out as soon as we get our hands on 6.4 Xcode beta :)

Comment: We confirmed that this bug is not present using Xcode 6.4 beta ! Once again - Thanks Mike :)